# How display several PDF pages using PDFBox

Tags: java, applet, pdfbox, japplet

I'm using **PDFbox** to render a PDF with multiple pages and forms, in a **java applet**, that it's going to be used in an **HTML page**. The applet needs to render all of the PDF pages one after another (vertically) and update the render when form values change.

Currently, for each `PDPage` in the `PDocument`, I'm creating a `PDFPagePanel` and adding it to a `JPanel`, that afterwards is being added to the `getContentPane()` Panel.

### Question:

1. Is there a better / more efficient way to do this, specially if it allows me to scale the applet and use the browser scroll, instead of implementing a scroll inside the panel ?

### JPanel creation code snippet:

```cs
public static JPanel createPanelWithAllPages(PDDocument pdfDoc) {
    JPanel docPanel = new JPanel();
    docPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(docPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    List<PDPage> docPages = pdfDoc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();

    for (PDPage page : docPages) {
        PDFPagePanel pagePanel = new PDFPagePanel();
        pagePanel.setPage(page);

        docPanel.add(pagePanel);
    }

    return docPanel;
}
```

Comment: Those are really two entirely separate questions that should be asked and answered on ..two separate threads.  SO is not a 'one stop - fix my problem shop', but a Q&A site.  Which question do you want to deal with on this thread?

Comment: The second question was actually an increment to the first question but, I can see why it may have come as two separate issues because, just like your *SO is not* remark, it was surplus and unnecessary. I've removed the extra information.